# How do i apply mods to minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I want to use mods in mincecraft but i dont know where to put the file or what to do with it once i have downloaded the mods... please help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the mod's website for installation instructions.

If for some reason there was nothing on the website, be sure to read the README file that was included with the mod.

If neither of those are available... no clue.

Which mod is in question?

Update:

http://www.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/balkons-weaponmod Installation instructions at the bottom

Couldn't find an official download page for Scenter (other than a Google Drive which I dont trust), but there is probably a readme.

MineForge: http://files.minecraftforge.net/

Comment: weaponmod-1.14.2 and scenter-1.7.2-3.1.0

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Comment: Do you by any chance know where I can download Minecraft Forge?

Comment: Ill update it again for you

Comment: It says "Move the downloaded weaponmod-v*.jar to the %appdata%/.minecraft/mods/ folder." but i don't have a mods folder. I was in the .minecraft folder and added in \mods but it says there is no mods folder. What do I do?

Comment: Try adding it? I dunno, I havent played minecraft in years

Comment: Another problem is that i dont have a bin folder...

Comment: Is Minecraft installed the normal way? Are you sure you're in the correct folder?